# Regex to extract links from a data frame and save as character string

Tags: r, regex, hyperlink

I have a data frame **df** with the columns **Sub and Text**. Need to extract a link from the Text column that has the keyword **Instance** and save them as character for future analysis. Tried below regex but it couldn't identify the links in the column.

Sample data and code mentioned below

Data - df

```
S.no            Sub                                                           Text                                         
  1        Link Information_UK      I have the link attached for data and copyright information for the UK region. Verify and let us know the feedback ."https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv"
                                    "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud _US_UK_List_1981_01_25.csv" 

  2       Information_US_UK     This information provides details for both UK and the US. Try extracting the data from the below link.    "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud _US_UK_List_1981_01_25.csv" 
  
  3       Welcome New joiners      This is a welcome mail for project information updates 

4        Link Information_Asia      I have the link attached for data and copyright information for the UK region. Verify and let us know the feedback ."https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/asiaCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv"
```

Code

```
k=df[df$Sub %like% "Link Information_UK", ]

if(df$Sub=Link Information_UK)
{
  pattern="https?:\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*).csv"
  m <- gregexpr(pattern, k$Text)
  regmatches(k$sub, m)
}
```

Expected Output:

m= "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud _US_UK_List_1981_01_25.csv"
m1= "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/asiaCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv"

Comment: 1. Add data in reproducible format using `dput` preferably. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). 2. You mention `Need to extract a link from the Text column that has the keyword 'Instance'`. In your attempt nowhere have you included `'Instance'`. 3. Why are you doing `k=df[df$Sub %like% "Link Information_UK", ]`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sub` here:

```
df$Link <- ifelse(grepl("https?://[^\"]+Instance", df$Text),
                  sub("^.*\"(https?://[^\"]+Instance.*?)\".*$", "\\1", df$Text),
                  "")
```

The logic here is that if we detect the start of a URL in the `Text` column using `grepl`, then we attempt to match and capture it using `sub`.  Otherwise, we just return empty string.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I need only the link which has the keyword "Instance" in it. The above code segregates rows with and without links. how to drill down further?

Comment: @Meenu Check the updated answer which now only matches URLs containing `Instance`.

Comment: Tried updating the code, but I get the same output as the previous one.

Comment: You need to reload your page, and I think you haven't done that.

Comment: I reloaded and saved them in the new column as shown below just to differentiate, but no luck.      
df$Link1 <- ifelse(grepl("https?:", df$Text),
                  sub("^.*\"(https?://[^\"]+Instance.*?)\".*$", "\\1", df$Text),
                  "")

Comment: TimBiegeleisen, would it be better to use an initial `grepl("https?:.*Instance", .)` as the ifelse conditional? Without more of a pattern, this might trigger on the `https?:` but not find `"Instance"` and return the whole un-`sub`'d string.

Answer (score 0):

Another method might be to extract all links and then filter for `Instance` separately.

```r
vec <- c("I have the link attached for data and copyright information for the UK region. Verify and let us know the feedback .\"https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\"", "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud _US_UK_List_1981_01_25.csv", "This information provides details for both UK and the US. Try extracting the data from the below link.    \"https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud _US_UK_List_1981_01_25.csv\"", "This is a welcome mail for project information updates ", "I have the link attached for data and copyright information for the UK region. Verify and let us know the feedback .\"https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/asiaCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\"")

regmatches(vec, gregexpr("https?://[^ ]*", vec))
# [[1]]
# [1] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\""
# [[2]]
# [1] "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud"
# [[3]]
# [1] "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud"
# [[4]]
# character(0)
# [[5]]
# [1] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/asiaCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\""
```

(Admittedly, this regex might be a little naive with regards to legitimate URLs.)

Let's change the `character(0)` to `NA` and reduce to a vector. (Side note: if there are multiple valid links in one string, then this also has the effect of `head(., 1)`.)

```r
out <- sapply(regmatches(vec, gregexpr("https?://[^ ]*", vec)), `length<-`, 1)
out
# [1] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\"" 
# [2] "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud"                                    
# [3] "https://s3.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud"                                    
# [4] NA                                                                                                
# [5] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/asiaCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\""
```

And now we can either filter out the ones we want or replace the non-matching elements with `NA` (e.g., to be able to put this data back into a frame with the original text).

```r
out[grepl("Instance", out)]
# [1] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\"" 
# [2] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/asiaCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\""
out[!grepl("Instance", out)] <- NA
out
# [1] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/abcCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\"" 
# [2] NA                                                                                                
# [3] NA                                                                                                
# [4] NA                                                                                                
# [5] "https://s33.aws.com/abc-inventory/abcloud/2021_01_25/asiaCloud_US_Instance_List_1981_01_25.csv\""
```